# detect tab changes on a repo

Tags: git, diff, whitespace

Say you have a repo with changes replacing tabs with spaces. I have uploaded one ad-hoc repo

```
$ git clone https://github.com/albfan/whitespace-diff
$ cd whitespace-diff
$ cat -A file1
text$
^Ianother text$
^I^Itext$
$ git checkout HEAD^
$ cat -A file1
text$
^Ianother text$
^I   text$
```

If you ask git for changes you get

```
$ git checkout master
$ git diff HEAD^
diff --git c/file1 w/file1
index 69e1c73..82d1284 100644
--- c/file1
+++ w/file1
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 text
        another text
-          text
+               text
```

which replaces itself tabs with spaces

How can one get this kind of diff:

```
$ diff -u <(git show HEAD^:file1 | cat -A) <(git show HEAD:file1 | cat -A)
--- /dev/fd/63  2016-01-31 23:21:52.341506890 +0100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2016-01-31 23:21:52.341506890 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 text$
 ^Ianother text$
-^I   text$
+^I^Itext$
```

and see real tab substitutions? Here there's only a file involved in diff, but on commits with several files implied get this output can be a nightmare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe the output to a filter that handles this substitution for you. This is a Perl one-liner.

```
git <options> | perl -p -e 's/\t/^I/g' | less
```

Comment: That definitely works. This is my final solution for a two side color diff `cdiff -s < <(git diff <ref1> <ref2>  | perl -p -e 's/\t/^I/g')` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdiff/0.9.6